# Right way to estimate test error of an optimized model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

*Context:*

According to the workflow recommended by Muller's "Introduction to Machine Learning with python", one would do a single score evaluation on a test set that was left aside at the beginning of the process:

[image]

This has the advantage to get a given model with its hyperparameters set, over nested cross validation that could use multiple (different) models.

Evaluation over a single test set gives an estimator that has high variance.

*The question:*

Is there any way to get a better generalization error estimation than this single score? (even if this method requires more training iterations)

Answer (score 1):

The workflow is perfect, but I think your model needs some work. 
You may divide the dataset in Training/Validation/Test set. Then you can train on your training data using cross validation, keep testing on the validation set till you get good results and then as a final step use the test data.